# Getting back to side bar after detaching layer panel in QGIS

Tags: qgis, toolbar, default, panel

I accidentally clicked on the detach icon on the layer side panel of QGIS and now it floats and I cannot get it back to the side bar where I want it.

Comment: Drag your layer panel to left side of screen....it will fit automatically.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just double click on the layer panel window title (applies to QGIS 2 and 3).

Comment: It is the perfect answer. Maybe just add "panel window title" to be precise.

Comment: In QGIS3, it works to bring the browser and layers windows into the same panel, but the combined panel is still undocked. How does on dock the whole panel back into the left sidebar?

Comment: Doesn't happen with my QGIS 3.2. The browser window wouldn't dock though just by doubleclicking its window title - only the layers window does. Maybe closing the browser window before doubleclicking the layers window helps?

Comment: It works with the toolbox panel window (double click and it floats, double click again and it docks), but it does not work with layers style editor window. QGIS 3.8.2. Is there a way around to arrange windows docking/floating?

Answer (score 9):

Double-clicking the title bar of floating windows on MacOS will maximize the floating window instead of docking it. I tried dragging the floating window to the approximate location of where the panel was docked but it didn't work. I restarted QGIS 3.6 and dragging the window appears to work again, and other panels will "slide" out of the way to make room for dropping the floating panel.

[image: Dropping a floating panel window into the sidebar in QGIS]

Comment: restarting then dragging did the trick

Comment: thank you! does anyone know if this is filed as a bug in QGIS?

Answer (score 3):

Inability to dock floating "Layers" panel is still a bug in QGIS 3.10-5 (LTR) on Windows 10 1909. However, as others have suggested restarting QGIS then immediately double-clicking the "Layers" title bar successfully docked it for me.

This is reported as 2 related bugs in the QGIS GitHub issues page here:

- https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/29177 (Feb-Sept 2019)
- https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/29909 (May 2019)

Answer (score 1):

Workaround in the QGIS console (will force-dock all panels):

```py
for w in iface.mainWindow().findChildren(QDockWidget):
    w.setFloating(False)
```