# Attaching toolbar in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, toolbar

I have a similar problem to [Getting back to side bar after detaching layer panel in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/57323/getting-back-to-side-bar-after-detaching-layer-panel), but with toolbars.

So I accidentally detached digitizing toolbar (and other toolbar as well), and cannot put it back. I tried double click, untick and tick it again in Menu View - Toolbar, hovering it for several seconds over the empty toolbar place, none works.

Anybody know how?

[image: floatingg]

Comment: I don't have enough rep to comment above but I encountered the same problem (not snapping in despite hovering) and found this page while searching for help. Here's what solved it for me: QGIS was full screen/maximized when I had the problem. When I used the "restore down" button (top right by X) on the window to make it a partial-screen window, the interface started allowing the toolbars to snap back in.

Answer (score 1):

Just click and keep holding of the left end side of the toolbar and move it to the place you want.

Comment: Did that, I hover it on the former place for 10 seconds, nothing happened. It just keeps floating over other toolbar

Comment: Could you show me a screenshot of the problem?

Comment: Yes, i just upload the screenshot in the question.

Comment: Which version of QGIS are you using? It looks strange that you cannot return the toolbar to its location.

Comment: 2.12.3 Lyon. Yep, it suppose to be a really simple step to attached it back, but it simply won't.

Answer (score 0):

Me too I faced the same problem. I think its bug and QGIS community need to fix it. I faced the problem mainly with the layer panel. What finally helped me ws to hold the panel with the left mouse key and drag it back to the side. It migh not work initially but keep trying and it will solve the issue.